# I want to mock the response from external url

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit5, wiremock

i am working on a springboot based application and one of my rest api end point flow is as below

from controller >>> service>> clientclass

in client class i am calling a external post request using restTemplate. but as of now external url is down. so i need to mock the response from external url to test the entire flow from controller class and back

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a [mcve] for what you have so far. Showing code along with the verbal explanation will increases the chance of getting help more quickly.

Comment: One option is [WireMock](https://wiremock.org/docs/junit-jupiter/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did in one of my Projects to test a retry logic. Just remove the 503 responses and add the wanted body:

```
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertThrows;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertTrue;

import TestedApi;
import MyDto;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockResponse;
import okhttp3.mockwebserver.MockWebServer;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Tag;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.test.context.ActiveProfiles;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

@SpringBootTest()
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@Tag("integration")

public class TrApiIT {

  @Autowired
  private TestedApi testedApi;

  @BeforeEach
  void setup() {

  }

  @Test
  public void testRetryHappyPath() throws IOException {
    MockWebServer mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();

    mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(503));
    mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(503));
    mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setResponseCode(200)
        .setBody(""));

    mockWebServer.start(50455);

    List<MyDto> entries = List
        .of(MyDto.builder()
            .messageReference("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000")
            .build());

    Mono<HttpStatus> responseMono = testedApi.postData(entries);

    StepVerifier.create(responseMono)
        .expectNext(HttpStatus.OK)
        .expectComplete().verify();

    mockWebServer.shutdown();
  }
}
```

application-test.properties:

```
external.api.myapi.baseUrl=http://127.0.0.1:50455
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
  <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
  <version>${mockwebserver.version}</version>
  <!--<scope>test</scope>-->
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
  <version>${mockwebserver.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
  <version>${junitvintage.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
  <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
  <version>${reactortest.version}</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```